# javascript prints only half of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to print an element (body) using jquery plugin https://github.com/jasonday/printThis , but it only prints half of the element(vertically) , So I need to print the entire element , it's not only with the plugin, I tried raw javascript : `window.print();` and still having the same problem, here is my js:

```
print: function (jqueryElement) {
      //jqueryElement.printThis();
      window.print();
},
```

Also I tried this in my css:

```
@media print {
      body {
          width: 100%;
      }
}
```

please help !
EDIT: I forgot to mention that I use bootstrap 3 framework

Comment: Can you post your HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Use the .ajax jQuery provides to see what your DOM is doing actually using what I have here.

```
$.ajax({
    print: function(errorProneWindowElement) {
    window.print();
 }
success: function( result ) {
    $( "#elementTagDescriptor" ).html( "<elementFrameCalled>" + result + "          </elementFrameCalled>" );
  }
 });
```

Creating from the script your html also gives information..